# Why Java MySQL connection can't detect change that made by trigger?

Tags: java, mysql, loops, triggers, database-connection

I have a problem and need some enlightenment here..

I am using trigger to detect change made to my database, means that I set all my table with trigger for insert, update, and delete (MySQL)

Then I write that change into a table that I have made specifically to contain all information about the change. Let's name it xtable. (This table is not equipped with trigger)

My Java program need to continuously read that xtable to let other application know about the change.

Well the problem is, when I read the xtable in a loop, I can only read the initial value of the xtable that is when I established the connection to the database. (connection is established outside the loop)

If a change has been made to the database which will lead to new row in xtable, this new row which is produced by the trigger is not detected no matter how many times I read it with executing "select * from xtable" query..

The code look like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Connection conn = null;

    try {
        conn = database.getConnection();
        Statement state = conn.createStatement();
        String query = "select * from `xtable`;";

        while (true) {
            ResultSet rs = state.executeQuery(query);

            while(rs.next){
                // Some code for letting the other application know of the change
            }
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
    } finally {
        if (conn != null) {
            conn.close();
        }
    }
}
```

So basically if I run the program while the xtable is empty, I always gain an empty ResultSet even when there is a new row after sometimes.

Actually this problem can be solved by established the connection inside the loop, but then it will lead to another problem because it will consume more and more resource as the loop go around. (I have already try this and it will eventually use all resource on my computer after sometimes even when I have already properly closed it)

So can anyone please give me some suggestion what to do?

This is my first time posting a question here, I am sorry if there is some rule that I don't follow and please give me the right direction.

Comment: This is a very bad design.  Consider using a message queueing system such as [zeromq](http://www.zeromq.org/) publish/subscribe instead.

Comment: Close your ResultSet after the inner-while loop.  Make sure your Connection is using Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED isolation level, and create your statement like this: state = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);

Comment: Make sure the code that is causing the trigger is either auto-commit or you are explicitly committing the insert/update.

Comment: @JimGarrison By you mean bad design can you be more specific? Does that mean I should not use trigger? If not use trigger how should I detect change on the database?

Comment: @brettw Hey, I just try your suggestion and now its worked! I think the problem is I don't specify any transaction isolation and then by default phantom reads may not occur here. I suspect the range lock are set but I still don't understand why the trigger still can write to the table if it is the case. Thanks for your answer. And please do explain the correct explanation to me if it is possible :)

Answer (score 1):

Thereis such thing as transaction isolation.  It could be possible that your connection  does not see changes because you did not commited transaction coming from trigger, or  you did not started new one on client side.  Impossible to tell without seeing your database set up.

PS:  Message queuing is way better alternative

Comment: Hi, thx for the info. I just read some explanation about transaction isolation and it looks like I still have some studies to do.. The application that update the database is autoCommit since I don't specify anything. @brettw already give me the solution and the problem lies in the fact that I don't specify any transaction isolation level when I read the table. So I think phantom reads are not allowed here or something like that. By the way, thank you very much for mentioning transaction isolation, I really learn a lot from that..

Comment: Oh, and about the message queuing. Do you mean to use it as alternative for the trigger or just for how to let the other application know? I read about it but I don't understand how it can be alternative for trigger to detect change on database..

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd better consider trigger instead of querying to the DBMS by looping.

If you use trigger you don't have to use that 'while' loop from Java side to check the change of DB.
Instead, trigger mechanism which is embedded in the DBMS will notify the Java side when the change happens.

For Oracle, you can call Java method from PL/SQL.
For PostgreSQL, you can call Java method from PL/Java.
For CUBRID, you can call Java method from Java stored procedure.

For MySQL, you can call Java method but I don't think it is as easy as above.
I wish this link would help you out. http://code.rocksol.it/call-java-from-mysql-trigger
Or google this keyword, "mysql java user defined functions"

Answer (score 0):

```
  Connection connection=getConnection();
  statement="query";
  try {
            stmt = connection.prepareStatement(statement);
              ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {

        }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (connection != null && stmt != null) {
                stmt.close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.